# How to show correctly filled fields value if the form shows errors during submission?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I use following code to create form. The form has text fields, check box, dropdown menus and text area.
I could show the text fields values during the form submission if it's filled correctly and shows error message to th fiels which are not filled correctly. 
I want to do the same for checkbox, dropdown and text area. If the check box checked for YES then form should show checkbox selected YES if the form contains unfilled or incorrectly filled fields during the form submission.
I save fields values like this:

```
$sender = $_POST["sendername"];
$name_title = $_POST["name_title"];
$pick_up_yes = $_POST["pick_up_yes"];
$pick_up_no = $_POST["pick_up_no"];
$special_req = $_POST["special_req"];
```

Validation:

```
if(empty($sender)){
 //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
 $errors['sendername'] = "Please enter your name!";
        }
if($name_title === none){
 //if selected is none, add error to $errors array.        
 $errors['name_title'] = "Please select the title of your name!";
}
if (($pick_up_yes != yes) && ($pick_up_no != no)){
 //Blank string, add error to $errors array.        
 $errors['pick_up_no'] = "Please let us know your airport pick up requirement!";
}
```

HTML FORM:

```
<div class="form-label">Title</div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <select name="name_title" class="name-title-input">     
            <option value="none" selected="selected">Select Title</option>
            <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
            <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div class="error-msg">
    <?php if(isset($errors['name_title'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['name_title'].'</span>'; } ?>
    </div>  
<div class="form-label">Name</div>
<div class="form-input">
    <input type="text" name="sendername" value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $sender;} ?>" />
    <div class="error-msg">
        <?php if(isset($errors['sendername'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['sendername'].'</span>'; } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-label">I need Airport pick-up</div>
    <div class="form-input">
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up_yes" value="yes" />Yes 
        <input type="checkbox" name="pick_up_no" value="no" />No
<div class="error-msg">
<?php if(isset($errors['pick_up_no'])) { echo '<span style="color: red">'.$errors['pick_up_no'].'</span>'; } ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-label">Write us in details if you have any special requirement</div>
    <div class="form-input">​
    <textarea name="special_req" value="<?PHP if(!empty($errors)) { echo $special_req;} ?>"></textarea>
    </div>
```

I get "sendername" value only saved if the form submits with errors when I see form again.
How can I get the selected check box, dropdown and text area saved / selected value when the form shows errors?

Comment: Are you looking for how to save the good data to your db if some values are correct and others are not or are you looking to solve the issue of reporting back to the user which fields are incorrect or show their previous inputs and notifying them which ones need to be changed?

Comment: No and Yes.. actually this is not DB connected form.. this form is sent to an email when it's submitted. 
and Yes "if some values are correct and others are not or then I want to solve the issue of reporting back to the user which fields are incorrect or show their previous inputs and notifying them which ones need to be changed"

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would probably do is change

```
 if($name_title === none){
```

To

```
if($name_title == "none"){
```

Or just make that a blank value and use empty quotations instead.

Also

```
if (($pick_up_yes != yes) && ($pick_up_no != no)){
```

Can be

```
if ($pick_up_yes == ""){
```

If you set your values to 1 for yes and 0 for no

To accomplish what you are looking for, say

```
<?php 
    if($_POST['inputName'] == 'myInputValue'){
        $checked = 'checked';
    }
    else{
        $checked = '';
    }

    if($_POST['inputName2'] == 'myInputValue2'){
        $checked2 = 'checked';
    }
    else{
        $checked2 = '';
    }

    if($_POST['inputName3'] == 'myInputValue3'){
        $selected3 = 'selected';
        $selected4 = '';
    }
    else if($_POST['inputName3'] == 'myInputValue4'){
        $selected4 = 'selected';
        $selected3 = '';
    }
    else{
        $selected = '';
    }
?>

<input type='checkbox' <?= $checked;?> name='inputName' value='myInputValue'/>

<input type='checkbox' <?= $checked2;?> name='inputName2' value='myInputValue2'/>

<select name='inputName3'>
    <option <?= $selected3; ?> value='myInputValue3'> pick </option>
    <option <?= $selected4; ?> value='myInputValue4'> me </option>
</select>

<textarea name='inputName4'> <?= $special_req; ?> </textarea>
```

The key is knowing where your values are populated in an input and echoing the value that was previously posted via your form:-)

Comment: Thanks for that optimized code.. but this is not the answer for the question

Comment: True but simplifying the code is first step in understanding where there are issues causing it to not save